# Error during renaming a package in B1if Integration Framework BPE139 Failure to obtain a lock

Tags: sapb1

I'm trying to rename a disable package in business one integration framework, and i get this error :

[image: error image => click here]

Any idea how this could be fix !?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an error in the file so try to rename the package in the xml file. Export the package and then find the xml line where the name is defined. Change it and import the changed package. I had trouble with some funktions in some browers so maybe try an other one.